# How can I break down the strings listed below with tcl

Tags: tcl

I can have several possible strings such as "1, 1203;2 59", "1, 1203;2 59;3 44" or "1, 1203;3 44".  The way I need to read this is "1" has a value of 1203, "2" has a value of 59 and "3" has a value of 44.  There will always be at least one  entry with the format "number" space "value" but there can be up to three sets of entries in the string (like the second example shown above).

Comment: Is it inconsistent in the use of commas?

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
set str1 "1, 1203;2 59;3 44"
```

you may need to split the string first:

```
set str1_list [split $str1 ";"]
```

then you can use "regexp" for each item parse:

```
regexp {(\d+),* *(\d+) *$} [lindex $str1_list 0] -> res1 res2
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample code:

```
proc foo {data} {
    array set return_value {}
    foreach item [split $data ";"] {
      set elements [split $item]
      set key [string trimright [lindex $elements 0] ","]
      set value [lindex $elements end]
      set return_value($key) $value
    }
    return [array get return_value]
}
array set tmp [foo  "1, 1203;2 59"]
puts [parray tmp]
unset tmp

array set tmp [foo  "1, 1203;2 59;3 44"]
puts [parray tmp]
unset tmp

array set tmp [foo  "1, 1203;3 44"]
puts [parray tmp]
unset tmp
```

Execution output:

```
tmp(1) = 1203
tmp(2) = 59

tmp(1) = 1203
tmp(2) = 59
tmp(3) = 44

tmp(1) = 1203
tmp(3) = 44
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a string to define an associative relationship between some keys (1, 2, 3) and some values (1203, 59, 44). In Tcl, this relationship can be expressed simply as the value

```
{1 1203 2 59 3 44}
```

Let's see if we can translate the given string into this value. Let's strip away any commas and replace all semicolons with spaces:

```
% set data [string map {, {} ; { }} "1, 1203;2 59;3 44"]
1 1203 2 59 3 44
```

And we're done. Testing:

```
% dict get $data 1
1203
% dict get $data 2
59
% dict get $data 3
44
```

Documentation:
[dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)